# Unable to create/write to a file using class member function in c++

Tags: c++, class, fstream, file-handling

This is MedClass.cpp :-

```
#include "MedClass.h"


std::string Medicine::getFileName()
{
    return file_name;
}

std::string Medicine::getMedicineName()
{
    return med_name;
}

std::string Medicine::getMedicineFormula()
{
    return med_formula;
}

void Medicine::displayMedInfo()
{
    std::cout << "Details of selected medicine : \n\n";
    std::cout << "Medicine name :- " << med_name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Medicine formula :- " << med_formula << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Medicine weight :- " << med_weight << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Medicine Price :- " << med_price << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Medicine Expiry Date :- " << expiry_date << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Meicine Comapny :- " << med_company << std::endl;
}

int Medicine::getMedUnitsLeft()
{
    return med_units_left;
}

void Medicine::writeToFile()
{


    medicine_file.open(file_name);
    std::cout << "Enter details of medicine in following format :- \n";
    std::cout << "Name Formula Weight Price Company Expiry\n";
    getline(std::cin, file_input);
    medicine_file << file_input;
    medicine_file.close();
    std::cout<<"File input validated : \n";
}

void Medicine::getFromFile()
{
    medicine_file.open(file_name);
    medicine_file >> 
med_name>>med_formula>>med_weight>>med_price>>med_company>>expiry_date;
    medicine_file.close();
}

void Medicine::createFile()
{


    medicine_file.open(file_name);
    if (!medicine_file.is_open())
        std::cout << "file is not opening\n";
    medicine_file.close();
}

void Medicine::setFileName(std::string &recieved)
{
    file_name = recieved;
}
```

This is MedClass.h :-

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>

class Medicine
{
public :

    std::string getFileName();
    std::string getMedicineName();
    std::string getMedicineFormula();
    void displayMedInfo();
    int getMedUnitsLeft();
    void writeToFile();
    void getFromFile();
    void createFile();
    void setFileName(std::string &recieved);


private:

    std::fstream medicine_file;

    std::string file_name;
    std::string file_input;
    std::string med_name;
    std::string med_formula;
    std::string expiry_date;
    std::string med_company;
    float med_weight;
    float med_price;
    int med_units_left;
};
```

Now, if i implement it in main.cpp  in this way :-

```
void ViewMedicine()
{
    Medicine med;
    std::string medicine_name;
    std::string medicine_filename;
    std::cout << "Enter medicine name to view : \n";
    getline(std::cin, medicine_name);
    medicine_filename = "Medicines\\" + medicine_name + ".txt";
    std::ifstream check_med_by_name;
    check_med_by_name.open(medicine_filename);
    if (!check_med_by_name.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Medicine not found\n";

    }
    else
    {
        med.setFileName(medicine_filename);
        med.getFromFile();
        med.displayMedInfo();
        check_med_by_name.close();
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::string medicine_name;
    std::string medicine_filename;
    Medicine medic;
    std::cout<<"View Existing Medicines \n";
    ViewMedicines();
    std::cout<<"Enter the name of medicine to add : \n";
    getline(std::cin,medicine_name);

    medicine_filename = "Medicines\\" + medicine_name + ".txt";
    medic.setFileName(medicine_filename);
    medic.createFile();
    medic.writeToFile();
    return 0;
}
```

Here if the program runs correctly, it should create a file inside medicines folder and should not display "file not opening" in the output.But i am getting "file is not opening" as the program output.this shows that the file is not getting created.Even manually creating the medicines folder does not help.

But I am able to view already existing manually created medicine file named med inside medicine folder.

Program output is something like this :-

```
View existing medicines
Enter medicine name to view :
med
Details of selected medicine :

Medicine name :- name
Medicine formula :- formula
Medicine weight :- 50
Medicine Price :- 100
Medicine Expire Date :- 10/04/21
Medicine Company :- company


Enter the name of medicine to add :
new
file is not opening
Enter details of medicine in following format :-
Name Formula Weight Price Company Expiry
new new 50 100 new 0
file input validated
press any key to continue...
```

So why am i able to view already existing medicine file but not able to create a new one using the member function CreateFile() ?what should i do to create a new medicine file with all the details so i can access it later.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Have you checked behavior of `open` function (with default arguments)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it seems like i solved it.If i add a minor change to createFile() function,the program runs perfectly.

```
void Medicine::createFile()
{


    std::ofstream medicine_file(file_name);
    if (!medicine_file.is_open())
        std::cout << "file is not opening\n";
    medicine_file.close();
}
```

I changed the first line from "medicine_file.open(file_name)" to "std::ofstream medicine_file(file_name)" and it runs as expected.

Comment: (See my answer.)
Also, here you create a local variable which will be destroyed after you exit the function. Better will be use class member. 
Also, check the error state of the operations.

Answer (score 0):

1) Default `fstream` mode will not create a new file.

```
`std::fstream medicine_filename;
 ...
 medicine_file.open()'
```

[open()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) will not create a new file as the default mode is `in | out`. To create a file first, you need to specify `out` mode only.

2)    medicine_filename = "Medicines\" + medicine_name + ".txt";

Check, that the 'Medicines' directory exists. To test, try to form the full path with drive, like "C:\\Temp\\test.txt".